# VS2010 Beta 2: Can't launch local help documentation

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In VS2010 Beta 2, from the Help Library Manager, after selecting local help, and downloading the VS Documentation, it won't launch.

Here's what I have installed:

[image]

Here's what I'm clicking in the Start Menu:

[image]

Here's the result:

[image]

Ideas?

Thanks,

Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had problems with VS 2010 Beta 2 help, or rather with MS Help 3, which is new with 2010 .  There is a known issue with the Help Listener Service trying to listen on port 80.  MS document a procedure to change this port, and my help was back up after following it.  From the the ReadMe_ENG.htm file that is installed with MS Help:

> 1. Removal of Help 3.0 will not remove content from user's machine;
>      they should run HLM to remove content
> 2. Product Documentation shortcut will not work after uninstall of Help
>      3.0
> 3. Help Library Manager requires the BITS service to be running if you
>      want to use the “Check for Updates” or
>      “Find Content online” features.
>      Removing content and installing
>      content locally does not require the
>      BITS service.
> 4. Help Library Manager will hang if you attempt to install offline
>      content but there is not sufficient
>      disk space for the BITS service to
>      download the content
> 5. If port 80 is used by another process (not via the http.sys service)
>      then the Help listener will not be
>      able to attach and use port 80 and
>      will fail.  The port number can be
>      changed by adding a string registry
>      value ListenerPort under
>      HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Help3
>      with the value of the port to use (eg.
>      81).  Due to the http.sys ACL settings
>      it is necessary to run the following
>      http.sys configuration command from an
>      admin elevated command line.  On
>      Vista, Win2k8, and Windows 7 run the
>      following native command: netsh http
>      add urlacl url=http://127.0.0.1:/help/ sddl=D:(A;;GX;;;WD)
>
> On Windows Xp, and Win2K3 run the
>   following command:
>
> httpcfg set urlacl /u
>   http://127.0.0.1:/help/
>   /a D:(A;;GX;;;WD)
>
> If the command is not found then it
>   might be necessary to download the
>   httpcfg.exe from Microsoft as part of
>   the Windows XP Service Pack 2 support
>   Tools
>   (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?amp;displaylang=en&familyid=49ae8576-9bb9-4126-9761-ba8011fabf38&displaylang=en).
>
> Now the Microsoft Help Listener will
>   run on the selected port number.

**ADDENDUM:** 
I also ended up installing MS Help 3 manually, and using the `Help->Manage Help Settings` menu command.  On the VS 2010 installation 'disk', I ran WCU\Help\HelpSetup.exe, after removing help via Add/Remove programs.  Note the folder HelpSetup installs to, and then in VS 2010, open the Help Library Manager (`Help->Manage Help Settings`), then Find Content on Disk, and then supply the location HelpSetup installed to.  Help 3 will take it from there.

Comment: Where you having troubles using local help or online help? It seems like I was able to download the local help without any errors.  In other words, that process didn't throw any errors.  But once "sucessfully" installed, it doesn't launch from the local source.  What was the error you encountered?  Thanks.

Comment: @Adam, it was local help.  I didn't have any net access at the time, and was getting desperate.  Check my additional info in my answer.

Comment: I had the very same issue, and it turned out to be Skype, because it always open port 80.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend reporting this bug on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/) so that the Visual Studio product team can take a look at this.

This seems like a rather specific problem and not a general programming question.

Comment: @Eilon, there are known and published issues with the help in VS 2010, a programming tool that falls under acceptable question topics.